# import c# winforms into excel,

Tags: c#, excel

Please show me the code how to import winforms controls, into excel xls. file.

I have created one winform in c#, but while taking print out  c#,
there s no table border lines, because in c# winforms onle table layout tools s present, so i need to import this to excel and convert to table format and take print out.

thank u.... i expect the answer from your side...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly don't really know what you're asking, but I'm going to take a guess that you want to host WinForms controls in an Excel workbook?

If so, you may find these MSDN articles useful:

- [How to: Add Windows Forms Controls to Office Documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b86d6w07.aspx)
- [Using Windows Forms Controls on Excel Worksheets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157869.aspx)

Otherwise, you'll need to clarify your question and ask something a little more specific.